# How to recursively extract custom icons from subfolders and save them in image files

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, icon

I am migrating from MacOS to Linux.
I have customized the icon of many of my sub-folders in my "Documents" folder.
I learned how to do the same in Linux, using image files, and now I would like to transport all my custom icons to my new system.

Since the number is quite high, I would like to automate this process: recursively copy the custom icon of all the subfolders, and save each of them in a separate image file (.png format?).

Maybe this could be done with an Automator script, but I am not proficient with that.

Comment: What is the suffix (.???) of this files?

Comment: If you changed these icons using Finder’s **Get Info** window, the images will be in the resource fork (extended attribute) of an invisible file in the folder root.  It would probably be easier to just copy the original images.

Comment: @red_menace Out of curiosity, shouldn't that affect the `kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon` value for the folder? I get `(null)`. Or are these unrelated? Also get same with a file when pasting an image into the Get Info icon well.

Comment: @Mockman - I’ve never seen the `kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon` show anything but `(null)`, so I don’t know if it is deprecated, referring to something else, or is just broken.  The `com.apple.ResourceFork` metadata is where the image data is actually stored, but it is a bit of a pain to get at, especially for folders.

Comment: @red_menace Thanks for the insight. I find it difficult to track down details for much of the myriad metadata in the filesystem as well as info on icons but this gives me something to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *example* **shell script** *code*, shown below, what tested under **macOS Catalina** saved as a *shell script* and executed in **Terminal**.

It makes use of the the *third-party utility* [**`fileicon`**](https://github.com/mklement0/fileicon), which is a *shell script* that use all native **macOS** functionality to extract the icons from the *folders* that have a custom icon. I used the manual installation instructions on the linked web page.

The *example* **shell script** *code* creates a working *folder* within the **Documents** *folder* with the naming convention of, e.g., **Documents Folders Images - 1632963703** where e.g. **1632963703** is the seconds since **epoch**. Within this *folder*, a *hierarchical folder structure* is created in the *qualified pathname* for each *folder* from the **Documents** *folder*, that has a custom icon, where an **.icns** *file*  is created as the extracted image and a **.png** *file* created from it. The *files/folders* are named according the *name* of the *folder* with the custom icon. This way you have no problem knowing where they go once moved to **Linux**.

To use the *example* **shell script** *code*, in **Terminal**, run the following *compound command*:

```
f='extracticons'; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod +x "$f"
```

Copy and paste the *example* **shell script** *code*, shown below, into the opened **extracticons** *document*, then save it.

You should then move the `extracticons` *shell script* to a *directory* located within the *shell's* `PATH`.

I moved it to `/usr/local/bin`, e.g,:

```
sudo mv -v extracticons /usr/local/bin/
```

Now it's ready for use, just type `extracticons` and press **enter**.

---

*Example* **shell script** *code*:

```zsh
#!/bin/zsh

doc_dir="$HOME/Documents"
icns_dir="${doc_dir}/Documents Folders Images - $(date +%s)"

while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ "${line}" =~ ($HOME/)(Documents/.*)(/Icon) ]] || continue
    mkdir -p "${icns_dir}/${match[2]}"
    cd "${icns_dir}/${match[2]}" || exit
    printf '%s\n' 'Creating .icns file...'
    fileicon get "${match[1]}${match[2]}"
done < <(find "${doc_dir}" -type f -name 'Icon?' -print)

while IFS= read -r line; do
    dir_path="${line%/*}"
    file_name="${line##*/}"
    cd "${dir_path}" || exit
    printf '%s\n' 'Creating .png file...'
    sips -s format png "${file_name}" --out "${file_name%.*}.png"
done < <(find "${icns_dir}" -type f -name '*.icns' -print)

cd "${icns_dir}" || exit
printf '%s\n' 'Creating Zip Archive...'
zip -r 'DocumentsFoldersIcons.zip' 'Documents'
printf '%s\n' "Deleting ${icns_dir}/Documents"
rm -r "${icns_dir}/Documents"
```

---

**Notes:**

The last *block* of *code* in the *example* **shell script** *code* creates a **zip archive** *file* of the *hierarchical folder structure* and then cleans up by deleting the *hierarchical folder structure*, leaving a *file* named **DocumentsFoldersIcons.zip** containing all of the icons created with their *paths* recursed. You can always comment it out or remove the `rm` *command* if you want.

This answer only covers the extraction of custom icons and the creation of a **.png** *file* from the **.icns** *file*. Assigning the icons to *folders* under **Linux** is outside the *scope* of appropriate questions for **Ask Different**. Posting a question at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would be more appropriate for the **Linux** side of things.

On a side note though, once you have extracted the **DocumentsFoldersIcons.zip** *files* on the **Linux** system, if you need different sizes of the image other than the one extracted by `sips`, you can use `icns2png` to extract all the icons in the **.icns** *files* to the various sizes within by doing the following in a **Terminal**:

```
cd '/path/to/extracted/Documents'
find . -type f -name '*.icns' -execdir sh -c 'icns2png -x "$1"' sh {} \;
```

<sup>Note that this assumes `icns2png` has been installed.</sup>

Then in each *folder* you will find, e.g.,:

```
Foldername.icns
Foldername.png
Foldername_16x16x32.png
Foldername_32x32x32.png
Foldername_48x48x32.png
Foldername_128x128x32.png
Foldername_256x256x32.png
Foldername_512x512x32.png
```

The *example* **shell script** *code* was tested in **Terminal** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

<sub>The *example* **shell script** *code* is just that, an example, and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed, or wanted. The onus in upon the user to ensure the *script* if fit for use for ones purpose.</sub>

Comment: This is brilliant! I will test it asap.

Comment: It works like a charm! thank you!!